# smarty include file a page with dynamic content

Tags: php, smarty

index.php includes some module pages, _head.tpl, _foot.tpl

**index.php:**

```
<{include file="_head.tpl"}>
....
<php?
  ....
?>
<{include file="_footer.tpl"}>
```

**_head.tpl**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<{include file="$baseUrl/menu/index"}>
.....
```

When opening the url: www.test.com/index shows "http 500 error"

Open the url: **www.test.com/menu/index** can get a dynamic content. Copy the content of list to the "_head.tpl" rather than the smarty sentence(**<{include file="$baseUrl/menu/index"}>**), the "**www.test.com/index**" shows well.

Answer (score 0):

You cant able to directly specific like this. You have to get the content using php file_get_contents or Curl.

refer here : http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=78900